# adding shade to R lineplot denotes standard error

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm looking for a R or ggplot2 solution for plotting a line with shade denotes standard error. Have been google'd a while without lucky.

[image: line plot with shade denotes SE]

Did anyone have similar experience and would like to share would be appreciated.

Sample code I used:

```
> dat <- read.table('sample',header=TRUE)
> ggplot(dat, aes(x=pos,y=value, colour=type))+geom_line()
```

The figure I generated:

[image: sample figure]

Sample data:

```
pos value   type
1   1.40685064701   A
2   1.58314330023   A
3   1.74204838899   A
4   1.61736939797   A
5   1.29508580767   A
6   1.09467905031   A
7   1.10472385941   A
8   1.02381316251   A
9   1.30213436484   A
10  1.70752481609   A
11  2.01875034644   A
12  1.82218601208   A
13  1.46976809915   A
14  1.78802276311   A
15  1.93459128836   A
16  1.95665864564   A
17  1.57026992442   A
18  1.15962402775   A
19  1.05305484021   A
20  0.919362594185  A
21  0.833060897559  A
22  0.77778822023   A
23  0.980084775745  A
24  1.32114351777   A
25  1.55352963275   A
26  1.57375922815   A
27  1.14493868782   A
28  0.25294849907   A
29  -0.40599118604  A
30  -0.487054890978 A
31  -0.333389189047 A
32  -0.226405253731 A
33  -0.24558780059  A
34  -0.180403027022 A
35  -0.266733706191 A
36  -0.0762920840723    A
37  0.465100892866  A
38  0.516633798421  A
39  0.644986315681  A
40  1.09115362242   A
41  1.08889196437   A
42  0.862434726048  A
43  0.604042272774  A
44  0.328584834197  A
45  0.598617257523  A
46  1.05219653601   A
47  1.10798332527   A
48  0.948151198722  A
49  0.546516443068  A
50  0.291735961134  A
51  0.238335006253  A
52  0.425304707962  A
53  0.817302425729  A
54  1.38852220304   A
55  2.34024990348   A
56  3.09941186364   A
57  4.06854366458   A
58  4.82115051043   A
59  4.55199542056   A
60  6.17279510607   A
61  10.3162999798   A
62  12.996627449    A
63  12.2731258622   A
64  10.8544867366   A
65  8.27264346102   A
66  5.79180739043   A
67  4.81947524098   A
68  4.19372954801   A
69  3.46244417879   A
70  2.69421581749   A
71  1.93753362259   A
72  1.54011797412   A
73  1.29959330498   A
74  1.21705330118   A
75  1.22382555287   A
76  0.952475753311  A
77  0.686398680367  A
78  0.747237736846  A
79  0.720306209509  A
80  0.463068694886  A
81  0.306876218733  A
82  0.121617637342  A
83  0.0460331524847 A
84  -0.0107323735891    A
85  -0.0629997057801    A
86  -0.19204582316  A
87  -0.371375773255 A
88  -0.42668686684  A
89  -0.326517894916 A
90  -0.277301361031 A
91  -0.0386177879973    A
92  0.0101084138435 A
93  0.0605269021344 A
94  0.182751080385  A
95  0.13310933252   A
96  0.27074048104   A
97  0.267598260699  A
98  0.349363089715  A
99  0.264445135486  A
100 0.218924366626  A
101 0.153338812341  A
102 -0.0679742801523    A
103 -0.30849875963  A
104 -0.28903625474  A
105 -0.188860043325 A
106 -0.204777388005 A
107 -0.1461100225   A
108 0.102433799309  A
109 0.122246106735  A
110 -0.105920831771 A
111 -0.21545039794  A
112 -0.135846098251 A
113 -0.105900152586 A
114 -0.247196889682 A
115 -0.312824264065 A
116 -0.251182865438 A
117 -0.0867113506532    A
118 0.00458490479941    A
119 -0.0960520134953    A
120 -0.235300588181 A
1   0.939235632937  A
2   1.28838263139   A
3   1.42730334901   A
4   1.22224614063   A
5   0.896759827332  A
6   0.642894836093  A
7   0.737029720141  A
8   0.774643396412  A
9   0.759420758029  A
10  1.04696772347   A
11  1.23504525458   A
12  1.0676601916    A
13  0.826029313299  A
14  1.14629521568   A
15  1.14142924359   A
16  1.22956581755   A
17  1.13136892357   A
18  0.800448368445  A
19  0.652191202322  A
20  0.498096263495  A
21  0.555339022027  A
22  0.545965232595  A
23  0.726231857788  A
24  0.849494247969  A
25  0.916259379894  A
26  0.879335232046  A
27  0.56575342831   A
28  0.108604596914  A
29  -0.225555689899 A
30  -0.320456274731 A
31  -0.230459986895 A
32  -0.042388319738 A
33  -0.0833366171628    A
34  -0.0460734786257    A
35  -0.229033279226 A
36  -0.175845833699 A
37  0.197716175342  A
38  0.28980276875   A
39  0.512487189675  A
40  0.683324573043  A
41  0.631659584895  A
42  0.522329104013  A
43  0.393330574908  A
44  0.168841230084  A
45  0.350442790229  A
46  0.72946349718   A
47  0.925052059705  A
48  0.821386076473  A
49  0.505908860228  A
50  0.297370018812  A
51  0.212971428154  A
52  0.390453125173  A
53  0.719985040719  A
54  0.977964675176  A
55  1.54450254277   A
56  2.14621503854   A
57  2.99079642364   A
58  3.39269707733   A
59  3.33188837547   A
60  4.10675880825   A
61  6.96009219664   A
62  9.04165938743   A
63  8.65369320149   A
64  7.94685353567   A
65  5.99410112792   A
66  4.270657622 A
67  3.74053623603   A
68  3.16701121242   A
69  2.34745227622   A
70  1.76409736552   A
71  1.51200803675   A
72  1.2907743594    A
73  1.00681298597   A
74  0.862744443537  A
75  0.91574368888   A
76  0.714689640717  A
77  0.517175945403  A
78  0.567676742354  A
79  0.59107492188   A
80  0.36357410485   A
81  0.136113295885  A
82  -0.0424484841936    A
83  -0.0580144665363    A
84  -0.0982479104419    A
85  -0.125561965887 A
86  -0.18724722966  A
87  -0.319063282063 A
88  -0.310923270725 A
89  -0.297680012209 A
90  -0.29067812137  A
91  -0.153124902802 A
92  -0.0832141989646    A
93  0.0360608269851 A
94  0.0692223913598 A
95  0.0301088137407 A
96  0.229967884645  A
97  0.286834318788  A
98  0.302023175627  A
99  0.172030225713  A
100 0.128331231506  A
101 0.0852383292109 A
102 -0.0890769934766    A
103 -0.28596925454  A
104 -0.277955689998 A
105 -0.213135107915 A
106 -0.187743795588 A
107 -0.156312203071 A
108 0.00927423989462    A
109 0.0950491919392 A
110 -0.103823712283 A
111 -0.263438354304 A
112 -0.169133590325 A
113 -0.119342668528 A
114 -0.184209907576 A
115 -0.153083100597 A
116 -0.118314865514 A
117 -0.0218234673043    A
118 0.0354090403385 A
119 -0.176859459446 A
120 -0.254330750514 A
1   1.31156238699   B
2   1.66603897664   B
3   1.8595569523    B
4   1.47610814343   B
5   1.13938772251   B
6   1.07959295698   B
7   1.0562167754    B
8   0.953732152873  B
9   1.27923353158   B
10  1.87416928486   B
11  2.29643917738   B
12  2.11874255833   B
13  1.81800847267   B
14  1.97156297894   B
15  1.95639491025   B
16  1.75903105961   B
17  1.36979841803   B
18  1.20025438569   B
19  1.15465650184   B
20  1.09201899355   B
21  0.948241309108  B
22  0.755764015696  B
23  0.89321992313   B
24  1.55401151175   B
25  1.7724765184    B
26  1.61741216053   B
27  1.19119499499   B
28  0.379190890768  B
29  -0.280643671284 B
30  -0.438517977457 B
31  -0.358544058104 B
32  -0.175439246148 B
33  -0.152975829581 B
34  -0.161103632796 B
35  -0.174444281478 B
36  0.0432634194416 B
37  0.426620630846  B
38  0.484334073737  B
39  0.619581343298  B
40  0.967283510405  B
41  1.15176486771   B
42  0.966602160933  B
43  0.690373835041  B
44  0.319762485659  B
45  0.558607945261  B
46  1.11704365618   B
47  1.35119752184   B
48  1.086453978 B
49  0.522235623898  B
50  0.331232373297  B
51  0.470526554506  B
52  0.88872478677   B
53  1.3777468901    B
54  1.98052619207   B
55  2.74167480929   B
56  3.71564209846   B
57  4.7554986573    B
58  5.35724571871   B
59  5.09994377564   B
60  6.79713731723   B
61  13.5623123968   B
62  19.9726094303   B
63  20.6985773902   B
64  19.5622430224   B
65  16.9252890116   B
66  13.785124688    B
67  12.0153484193   B
68  10.6335853944   B
69  9.23145636242   B
70  8.33279506304   B
71  7.11679306668   B
72  5.98971780649   B
73  4.81795605529   B
74  3.6240387853    B
75  3.17710512841   B
76  3.09525364338   B
77  2.94968830182   B
78  2.85812444624   B
79  2.41084230435   B
80  1.80196837641   B
81  1.18822582466   B
82  0.847087211338  B
83  0.844579278397  B
84  0.719435070951  B
85  0.373826290695  B
86  0.179833579104  B
87  0.10827105313   B
88  0.140513871238  B
89  0.36900575791   B
90  0.545788292614  B
91  0.588906392532  B
92  0.411607834074  B
93  0.436297519059  B
94  0.417543346098  B
95  0.420644053229  B
96  0.754192582582  B
97  0.865901044214  B
98  0.821331429891  B
99  0.859522528975  B
100 1.0698784309    B
101 1.12094185211   B
102 0.954696811999  B
103 0.635033784692  B
104 0.593828176146  B
105 0.662067791202  B
106 0.640073276401  B
107 0.773737194106  B
108 1.04778537143   B
109 1.14218831145   B
110 0.936124315428  B
111 0.761897172562  B
112 0.584860054282  B
113 0.568945253284  B
114 0.592650160898  B
115 0.363421418416  B
116 0.315516608971  B
117 0.556218161647  B
118 0.741402531046  B
119 0.73670589581   B
120 0.731201358535  B
1   0.914487112088  B
2   1.17888880951   B
3   1.34882572489   B
4   1.05705037522   B
5   0.767924473683  B
6   0.627155263031  B
7   0.661419743127  B
8   0.726639134719  B
9   0.904404934323  B
10  1.11446499538   B
11  1.32234502189   B
12  1.11272139974   B
13  0.80278277695   B
14  1.05206129918   B
15  1.03054952945   B
16  0.920053144065  B
17  0.890783999963  B
18  0.745241179888  B
19  0.753375762718  B
20  0.606204084282  B
21  0.439550558806  B
22  0.415665737741  B
23  0.511097171088  B
24  0.753958021098  B
25  0.915744174748  B
26  0.914912288237  B
27  0.650537400908  B
28  0.177843412682  B
29  -0.182744261137 B
30  -0.280968150367 B
31  -0.131322561837 B
32  -0.0936594361197    B
33  -0.111213723334 B
34  -0.0751949309223    B
35  -0.114901791545 B
36  -0.0165691620777    B
37  0.117705450621  B
38  0.195665130311  B
39  0.49300993106   B
40  0.748293222013  B
41  0.702261888166  B
42  0.579761929719  B
43  0.354296503405  B
44  0.0685749425124 B
45  0.276465165244  B
46  0.833851789425  B
47  0.952399770341  B
48  0.780124651512  B
49  0.389046185042  B
50  0.240762613037  B
51  0.334216612367  B
52  0.497505803488  B
53  0.759900678942  B
54  1.12736521148   B
55  1.77820644505   B
56  2.60137514  B
57  3.11618984654   B
58  3.21453966104   B
59  3.02507885677   B
60  4.10630457704   B
61  7.81645787291   B
62  11.474225964    B
63  12.4863009071   B
64  11.5994621204   B
65  9.5999931249    B
66  7.96585566708   B
67  7.08309536929   B
68  6.04261032076   B
69  5.26284702902   B
70  4.76880466452   B
71  4.10897764688   B
72  3.33692117069   B
73  2.6513184514    B
74  2.25667303445   B
75  1.83839013124   B
76  1.84439486988   B
77  1.74545691393   B
78  1.60528910561   B
79  1.42843608445   B
80  0.854469270873  B
81  0.563227776699  B
82  0.299704948636  B
83  0.270143019019  B
84  0.283668987216  B
85  0.181017474033  B
86  0.0822636124446 B
87  -0.0465301247043    B
88  -0.000460798489744  B
89  0.0926334491843 B
90  0.192295768771  B
91  0.29542265617   B
92  0.218214141112  B
93  0.145843998014  B
94  0.12500365606   B
95  0.147889577395  B
96  0.368717140352  B
97  0.580075802767  B
98  0.459540843701  B
99  0.459168312255  B
100 0.614213389976  B
101 0.627367541442  B
102 0.562408018057  B
103 0.31716603245   B
104 0.288874098133  B
105 0.303797627692  B
106 0.338691064084  B
107 0.336034553249  B
108 0.587964074115  B
109 0.649227026019  B
110 0.541946830382  B
111 0.542082081996  B
112 0.51192491824   B
113 0.327474693143  B
114 0.254878532604  B
115 0.134544321919  B
116 0.100368014222  B
117 0.211272916527  B
118 0.267339751552  B
119 0.30990753715   B
120 0.444492582364  B
```

Thanks again!

Comment: I think `geom_ribbon()` might be what you're looking for, but it will be easier to help you if you provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: @KaraWoo, thanks for fast comment. I tried `geom_ribbon` without success -,-

Comment: What is the desired output here? What standard error are you interested in calculating and how do you want to affect the color of the line? It seems you have one value at each position now. You can't calculate standard error with one observation.

Comment: @MrFlick, thanks for comment. I have 2 values for each data point. Still trying `geom_ribbon`, thanks for all.

Comment: So you want one line? Your sample image (red/black) has two. And then if you calculate the sd for the pair of points to do the coloring, what value are you going to use for the y height?

Comment: @MrFlick, for each type A or B and position I got 2 values. Coloring by A or B.

Comment: @dli I'm sorry, but that simply makes no sense at all. That doesn't explain the "gradient shade".

Answer (score 25, accepted):

As @MrFlick already said, you can't calculate a standard error for each x-value. However, there are several option you can consider.

**Option 1:** plot a loess smooth with a very small span with `stat_smooth` in which you can include a shaded area for the standard error:

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x=pos,y=value, colour=type)) +
  stat_smooth(method="loess", span=0.1, se=TRUE, aes(fill=type), alpha=0.3) +
  theme_bw()
```

this gives:
[image]

**Option 2:** as you have a high and a low values for each `x` value, you can plot seperate lines for the high and low values. You have to creat a high/low variable first:

```
dat$level <- rep(c("high","low"), each=120)
ggplot(dat, aes(x=pos,y=value, colour=type)) +
  geom_line(aes(linetype=level)) +
  theme_bw()
```

this gives:
[image]

**Option 3:** as you have a high and a low values for each `x` value, you can plot a `geom_ribbon` between the high and low value with:

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x=pos,y=value, colour=type)) +
  stat_summary(geom="ribbon", fun.ymin="min", fun.ymax="max", aes(fill=type), alpha=0.3) +
  theme_bw()
```

this gives:
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. Is there a way the change the color of the shade in your 1st smooth plot? like using the color similar to the line.

Comment: @dli See the updated answer. I've also updated the third option.